# Stream iterate can someone provide a walkthrough of this example code

Tags: scala

So for splitting a number into its digits I found this code

```
    def split(n: Int) = if (n == 0) List(0) else { 
    (Stream.iterate(n)(_/10)takeWhile(_!=0)map(_%10)toList) reverse
}
```

[code](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/11647.html)

which works but I couldn't explain to myself how the computation flows . Could anyone provide more insight into the intermediate steps it takes to go from

```
split(123) 
List[Int] = List(3,2,1)
```

It seems fairly straightforward but reading the method declarations and trying to work examples with calculator I failed to re-create myself the result.

Comment: Was specifically interested in Scala - everyone can have their own opinions but I enjoy the language and wanted further information on this.

Comment: @Barry I would strongly suggest not using infix / postfix syntax for non-operator methods. It's at least a little easier to see what's going on if you write `Stream.iterate(n)(_ / 10).takeWhile(_ != 0).map(_ % 10).toList.reverse`.

Comment: @TravisBrownt thanks that makes sense - I just used the code from that old mailing list question I found which worked but yes I agree for readability I prefer what you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's separate it into a stages:

```
(Stream.iterate(n)(_/10) // n - is first number, _/10 is function that recursively applied on given number
takeWhile(_!=0) // while result is not equal to 0
map(_%10) // got a list of numbers and take it by mod 10
toList)  // transform to list
reverse // take it in reverse order

scala> (Stream.iterate(123)(_/10)).takeWhile(_!=0).toList
res6: List[Int] = List(123, 12, 1)
```

Comment: so Using example of n = 123 does it yield 12.3, 1.23, .123, then move on to modulus ? Again trying to do with with calculator then 12.3 %10 , 1.23 %10, .123 %10 I still can't create 3,2,1

Comment: a little bit clarified my message. it gives 123 , (123/10) = 12, (123/10)/10 = 1